# ASP.NET MVC 4 route crashes on one specific keyword: Ekstranett

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using routing in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I'm experiencing a very strange problem. I am attempting to establish a route to an area named Ekstranett, but if I use Ekstranett as the first URL parameter I get an Internal Server Error. I can use any word except for Ekstranett and I find that very strange. This is my setup:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Exception",
            "Ekstranett/Exception/{action}/{*handle}",
            new { controller = "Exception", action = "General", handle = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "MyProject.Areas.Ekstranett.Controllers" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Support",
            "Ekstranett/Support/{action}/{*handle}",
            new { controller = "Support", action = "Tickets", handle = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "MyProject.Areas.Ekstranett.Controllers" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Ekstranett_default",
            "Ekstranett/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "MyProject.Areas.Ekstranett.Controllers" }
        );
```

If I change Ekstranett to something like Ektranett, Testing, Foobar or anything else it works perfectly, but if I use Ekstranett it does not. Does anyone have any clue as to why I'm experiencing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved! Ages ago I made a virtual directory called ekstranett, I deleted it and everything works wonderfully now!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it could be because Ekstranett is the name of the Area? Could be causing a routing collision of some kind. Out of interest, if you use all lower case within the route, does that work? (e.g. `"ekstranett/Support/{action}/{*handle}"`)

Comment: A collision due to being named the same as the area should not be the case, as it was previously called CustomerWeb with regard to both route and area. Changing it Ekstranett to lower case did not help, I am still experiencing the Internal Server Error. This kind of behaviour can occur when there is a folder with the name Ekstranett, but there is no such folder on the server so I have eliminated that option. I would very much like the route to be named the same as the area. Choosing a different name is not an option.

Comment: When route and area were both called `CustomerWeb`, did you experience this issue?

Comment: I did not. It worked perfectly, but CustomerWeb was only a working title. I'd like both area and route to be called Ekstranett.

Comment: This does not happen when I use Visual Studio's development server, but it does happen when I use IIS 7.5.